# Let $f:Z \times Z \to Z$ with $f(1,1)=2$ and $f(3,5)=6$. Estimate the $\ker f$ of $f$ and $f(0,5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $f:Z \times Z \to Z$ with $f(1,1)=2$ and $f(3,5)=6$. Estimate the $\ker f$ of $f$ and $f(0,5)$.

I am trying to solve this but i need any ideas or hints to start,any help would be interesting.

Comment: Is there any mention of $f$ being a morphism of some sort?

Answer (score 2):

Well, $f(1,1)=2$ and $f(3,5)=6$. Assuming that we have a homomorphism (?), then this tells us that $3f(1,1) = f(3,3)=6$. Hence $$f(3,5)-f(3,3)=f(0,2) = 0.$$

This should give us a hint as to the kernel, or at least a subset of the kernel.

Notice that $k\cdot f(0,2) = f(0,2k)=k \cdot 0=0$ for any integer $k$.

I would use a similar concept to get $f(0,5)$. Although, I am not sure we actually can figure out what $f(0,5)$ equals. There does not seem to be an integer linear combination between $(1,1)$ and $(3,5)$

Comment: There cannot be one: if $a+b\equiv 0\pmod2$ and $c+d\equiv0\pmod2$ then any linear combination of $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ will also sum to zero $\pmod 2$ (since its sum is the same linear combination of $a+b$ and $c+d$).

Answer (score 1):

A follow-up to Vladhagen's answer: $2f(0,1) = f(0,2) = 0$, so it seems that $f(0,1) = 0$. Then $f(0,k) = 0$ for every $k$.

Comment: Oh yes, that is good. A more generalized solution.